# How to start wirh custom result backend in celery?

Tags: python, django, celery, backend

In advance im sorry if I'm not so specific with my question.
I want to create a custom result backend but I don't know how to start and the documentation that I found is not very clear to me, does any of you know of any example or document that can guide me?
I was thinking on create a class and assignt it in my celery.py like this

```
RESULT_BACKEND='my_class'
```

But I doubt this works, any advice will be really helpful.

Thanks